# problem in intalling xdman

Tags: 14.04

I have tried to download the xtreme download manager via terminal by executing following from the command line:

```
add-apt-repository ppa:noobslab/apps.
apt-get update
apt-get install xdman
```

However I receive the following output:

```
Cannot add PPA: 'ppa:noobslab/apps'.
Please check that the PPA name or format is correct.
```

What is the cause of this and how to I solve the issues?

Answer (score 1):

You can add the ppa manually:

Just add the following line to your `/etc/apt/sources.list`:

```
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/noobslab/apps/ubuntu trusty main 
deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/noobslab/apps/ubuntu trusty main
```

Just run `apt-get update` afterwards.

Comment: after copy n paste of above in file sources.list ,i am not able to save sources.list

Comment: @gurpreetsingh Are you running your text-editor with sudo? The `sources.list` file is owned by root and your regular user doesn't have write permissions to the file. Try running a text-editor with sudo, such as `sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list` or `gksudo gedit /etc/apt/sources.list`.